# Galois group of intermediate fields

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, field-theory, galois-theory

Find all subfields $M \subset \mathbb{Q}(\zeta_{7})$ where $\zeta_7=e^{2\pi i/7}$ and determine $Gal(\mathbb{Q}/M)$ and $Gal(M/\mathbb{Q})$.

I've found that there are 2 intermediate fields
$L=\mathbb{Q}( \zeta_7 + \zeta_7^6)$ and $M=\mathbb{Q}( \zeta_7 + \zeta_7^2+ \zeta_7^4)$.
I've also found that $Gal(\mathbb{Q}(\zeta_7)/M)=\{\sigma_1, \sigma_2, \sigma_4\}$ and $Gal(\mathbb{Q}(\zeta_7)/L)=\{\sigma_1, \sigma_6 \}$ where $\sigma_a(\zeta_7)=\zeta_7^a$. I just need to find $Gal(M/\mathbb{Q})$ and $Gal(L/\mathbb{Q})$

Comment: $Gal(M/K)$ doesn't necessarily exist, because $M$ may not be Galois over $K$. In fact, $M$ is Galois over $K$ if and only if $Gal(N/M) \subset Gal(N/K)$ is a normal subgroup, in which case $Gal(M/K) \simeq Gal(N/K)/Gal(N/M)$.

Comment: This is assuming $N$ is Galois over $K$, of course. I'm just stating a part of the Galois correspondence theorem.

Comment: okay maybe I should have been more specific. I'll change the question!

Comment: "$\sigma_a = \zeta_7^a$" presumably you meant to say $\sigma_a(\zeta_7) = \zeta_7^a$?

Comment: Yes of course sorry

Comment: The tool needed to figure this out is precisely what I gave you in my first comment.

Comment: In this case the extension is abelian (even cyclic) so all the subextensions are automatically normal and thus the Galois groups exist...

Comment: @DustanLevenstein I have always used the definition ${\rm Gal}(M/K) = \{ \alpha \in {\rm Aut}(M) : \alpha(k)=k\ \forall k \in K \}$, which exists for any field extension.

Comment: @DerekHolt That's not standard. I know that's how Artin defines it, but most people only call the automorphism group a Galois group if the extension is Galois.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've already seen that $\text{Gal}({\mathbb Q}(\zeta_7)/{\mathbb Q}) \cong C_6$. You've also seen that $\text{Gal}({\mathbb Q}(\zeta_7)/M) \cong C_3$ and that $\text{Gal}({\mathbb Q}(\zeta_7)/L) \cong C_2$. By Galois Correspondence, $\text{Gal}(M/{\mathbb Q}) \cong C_6 / C_3 \cong C_2$ and $\text{Gal}(L/{\mathbb Q}) \cong C_6/C_2 \cong C_3$.

If you want these Galois groups explicitly, as groups of automorpmisms of the field extensions $M/{\mathbb Q}$ and $L/{\mathbb Q}$, note that in both cases you just have to find a single non-trivial automorphism; that will automatically generate the Galois group.

For $M/{\mathbb Q}$, the map sending $\zeta_7$ to $\zeta_7^6$ (i.e., $\sigma_6$ restricted to $M$) is the generator; note that it indeed leaves $\zeta_7 + \zeta_7^6$ invariant. For $L/{\mathbb Q}$, the map sending $\zeta_7$ to $\zeta_7^2$ (i.e., $\sigma_2$ restricted to $L$) is a generator; this one indeed leaves $\zeta_7 + \zeta_7^2 + \zeta_7^4$ invariant. The other one is $\sigma_4$ restricted to $L$.

Comment: what do you mean by $\sigma_6$ restricted to $M$?

Comment: $\sigma_6$ is an automorphism of ${\mathbb Q}(\zeta_7)$; and $M$ is a subfield of ${\mathbb Q}(\zeta_7)$. So I just mean the map $M \to M$, $\alpha \mapsto \sigma_6(\alpha)$ (which is well-defined, because $\sigma_6(\zeta_7 + \zeta_7^6) = \zeta_7 + \zeta_7^6$).